# AppFabric Resume command failure

Tags: workflow, appfabric, workflowservice

In AppFabric we see some suspended workflows. When we try manually to resume them we get error:

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://[server]/[webSite]/[folder]/[workflowFile].xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

What could be the reason for this error? Where should be this endpoint defined?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the result of net.pipe not being enabled on the site or application (bindings). If you enable full WCF diagnostic tracing you will see what the underlying problem is.

It can also be the result of a messed up config file. I once had to explicitly add the workflow control endpoint to the config myself.

Comment: Net.pipe is enabled on the server. WCF full diagnostics is not possible now bacause it is in production so the diagnostic is not that eaasy. I will double check the config file. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Try to make sure net.pipe is enabled as a *binding* on the Default Web Site in IIS , and also as an Enabled Protocol on the application. You should also check to make sure the identity of the process accessing the net.pipe endpoint has permissions to do so. Is it possible that you are trying to access the net.pipe endpointr remotely? If it is in production, ask the admins to enable WCF verbose tracing in AppFabric, attempt the Resume, and then send you the trace. If this fails, recreate the scenario in a development environment.